# Using FFMPEG via command line in android

Tags: android, command-line, ffmpeg

I want to use FFMPEG via COMMAND LINE in my android application.For this purpose:

1. I have cross-compiled the ffmpeg lib and got the libffmpeg.so
2. I have stored libffmpeg.so and the ffmpeg exectable in files directory of the my project.

This is the code i am using:

public class FFMPEGActivity extends Activity {

```
Process p;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] cmd =new String[4];
    cmd[0]="/data/data/com.example.ffmpegnew/files/libffmpeg";
    cmd[1]="-i";
    cmd[2]="mnt/sdcard/music/baba.mp4";
    cmd[3]="mnt/sdcard/music/outfile.mp4";

    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,null, new File("/data/data/com.example.ffmpegnew/files"));

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("exception"+e);
    }

}
```

}

This is the exception i am getting:

```
09-17 13:47:01.679: I/System.out(3752): exceptionjava.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/data/com.example.ffmpegnew/files/libffmpeg.so, -i, mnt/sdcard/music/baba.mp4, mnt/sdcard/music/outfile.mp4] Working Directory: /data/data/com.example.ffmpegnew/files Environment: null
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone please help..........i am totally frustrated.I will be more than thankful to you.

Comment: Why do you expect that to work?

Comment: Sir actually i want to access ffmpeg lib through that

Comment: can't i use ffmpeg through command line in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this won't work, unless you somehow manage to compile ffmpeg executable, place it somewhere in the file system , then access it through your native layer. Normally, though, they use libffmpeg API in android such as in [Dolphin Player](http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/source/checkout)

Comment: Sir i have ffmpeg executable file.Can't i place it in some app folder itself and then work with that like we work with ffmpeg in cmd prompt.

Comment: can you please help me with compiling ffmpeg? I am struggling to create a video by combining an audio and an image. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to try to run the library, not the ffmpeg executable. Note that even after fixing your **cmd** you will need extra tricks to load the libffmpeg.so, because Android loader does not load shared libs from **./**

I would suggest to build a statically linked **ffmpeg** executable to save hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Place `ffmpeg` and all the files it accesses on the internal card (obtain through `context.getDir("", 0)`.
After you do this, you will be able to run ffmpeg through `exec()`.

Some models, however, will refuse running this too.