# How to use the result of guardian-ffmpeg-Android?

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am trying to build ffmpeg on Android. There are many tutorials. Some are very old.
So I want to try one that can use newer version of ffmpeg and Android NDK.
After long time searching, I find one, [guardianproject / android-ffmpeg](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg#readme)

The project was updated several months ago.
NDK r8 is used. ffmpeg is put from online, so a latest version.

After I follow all the instruction, I am confused which result I should use, and how to use it.
The README mentions testing, like:

```
# embedding metadata into a matroska video /data/local/ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 \
    -attach attach.txt -metadata:s:2 mimetype=text/plain \
    -acodec copy -vcodec copy testattach.mkv
```

First, I fail to find the path: /data/local
Second, this is a command. How will I use it in Android?

Totall confused.
Any light?

Comment: have you built it on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you have successfully built the ffmpeg executable and understand the difference between static and shared libs in the build. If not you should read up on that before trying to exec it on the CLI in android.

I think that the author uses ffmpeg on the cli using either system.exec or processbuilder techniques to run and executable located on the phone in ./data/local/$yourSubDir....

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472242/using-ffmpeg-via-command-line-in-android) for discussion on ffmpeg on cli in android and note that alot of people prefer to use the full JNI route employing java interfaces to wrap calls to ffmpeg.main(). IMO the JNI route is more robust for apps you intend to distribute. But it works on the cli.

the tests that confused you are just expressions for using ffmpeg that would need to be called in android using the approach you prefer ( system.exec or processbuilder ). You can get familiar with the cli testing by simply running ffmpeg in windows/ linux in your dev environment. Get a shell there and play with samples mentioned in the ffmpeg faqs.

you can look at the halfninja project on git for more examples on JNI approach.