# Android ffmpeg: create video from sequence of images using jni

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have successfully build ffmpeg for Android and now I need to create video from sequence images so it look like animation video with some default audio. I have found some solution but it all says using command like.

How to do same thing using jni on Android?

Comment: this can be easily done using [javacv](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/)

Comment: hi,can u create video from the images?i am stuck with in last 2days,i am working on a app in which i have get images from libraries and then make a video of that images,,can you please help me out??

Comment: Sameer if you solved your problem then please share it to me this is a big issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065931/running-ffmpeg-as-library-in-android) requiring more chops with jni interfaces that running on CLI like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472242/using-ffmpeg-via-command-line-in-android)

You will probably need to do some more reading on the JNI interface and specifically how to integrate call on 'ffmpeg.main()' with the JNI.

Once you have that down, creating mp4 from list of photos and audio is kind of like following in android/JNI...

from git, an example of the [interface](https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264/blob/master/Project/src/uk/co/halfninja/videokit/Videokit.java)

Comment: Thank you for answer,i have get the more details from here https://github.com/JayH5/android-ffmpeg-cmdline